# Nginx - How to serve a static file to a particular user agent?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to restrict access to a particular json file for a certain user-agent using the configuration files in Nginx.

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root      /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
}

location /v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8118;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location = /v1/apischema {
    root    /usr/share/nginx/json;
        if ($http_user_agent ~ useragentname) {
            try_files /openapi.json;
            break;
        }
}
```

}

The idea is to restrict access to openapi.json for an internal user.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`try_files` can be used in a `server` or `location` block. See **Context:** in [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

There are a number of ways to achieve this.

Using `if`:

```
location = /v1/apischema {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ useragentname) {
        rewrite ^ /openapi.json last;
    }
}
location = /openapi.json {
    internal;
    root    /usr/share/nginx/json;
}
```

The `internal` directive prevents this URI being accessed directly. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

---

Or using `map` with `try_files`:

```
map $http_user_agent $apischema {
    ~useragentname  /openapi.json;
    default         /nonexistant;
}
server {
    ...

    location = /v1/apischema {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/json;
        try_files $apischema =404;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.